# How to measure change in growth rate between contiguous periods

Tags: time-series, trend

I recently conducted a simple time-series analysis on some data. In this time series, we observe two elements (red and blue) that affect the trend during alternating periods.

[image: Time series]

I want to measure how much better or worse one period type is from the other period type (A and B) by measuring the effect they have in the trend, in the sense of how much they change the trend when they appear. It's direction, magnitude, etc.

My approach involved fitting a linear regression model to each period in the data and then calculating and comparing the slopes, measuring the change in slope per period in percentage terms. However, I am unsure about the validity of my method. It feels somewhat weak and discrete.

Is there a standard or commonly used approach to measure the impact of each element on the trend? How should I best tackle this problem?

Comment: Maybe I could use non linear regression for the overall series, and also linear regression for each period, and predict with that linear regression the next period. Afterwards calculate the difference between a combination of both slopes predicted (the non-linear general, and the linear local) and the actual slope that happens in that period. Another option would be, instead of just using the previous period for linear regression prediction, use that one and all of the previous ones too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a more or less acceptable method, at least it's more accurate and continuous.

Basically, this is analogous to acceleration. If we think of the graph as representing the displacement of a car, and element A and B as riders that take turns riding the car, if we want the car to move the most distance possible in less time, we would think that the element that accelerates the most while they are riding is the best option.

In order to estimate this 'acceleration' I calculated the gradient of 2º order of the graph with NumPy (like calculating the second derivative) and then the area under the curve of this new graph for each period. This will tell me how much the rate of growth changes ('acceleration') during each period, and therefore which element tends to perform better 'riding' the graph.

```
y1_order = np.gradient(y, x)
y2_order = np.gradient(y1_order, x)
area_under_curve = np.trapz(y2_order[x_start:x_end], x[x_start:x_end])/distance
```

And the resulting plot is this:

[image]

Maybe is a bit hard to understand intuitively, because the AUC is the change of the change, but I think the results make sense. The first period is almost linear, no change in speed, so low AUC, the third period had the most slowdown so it had the lowest AUC (like hitting the brakes).

**EDIT**

I fixed the things I didn't like that much about this method and the results seem good.

Basically I extended the data as far back in time as possible, then I fitted a non linear equation to the data. Because the elements (different periods) should more or less cancel each other out, the assumption was that the overall trend wasn't really affected by them.

I repeated the same procedure but instead of obtaining the second derivative of the raw data itself I calculated (and normalized) the difference in the second derivatives of the raw data and the long-term fitted equation. Then I also modeled other cases that show the same pattern and calculated the residuals on this 'adjusted change in slope' given the other 'adjusted changes in slopes' in the other cases with linear regression (for each other case I also performed non linear regression, and the best equation fit was almost the same).

The resulting graph I obtained showed, I think, the true acceleration of each period, by eliminating the effects of the overall global trend already present in the whole series, and the global trend that affects all independently evaluated time-series that are related in some way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether the slopes significantly differ according to the time period, it is incorrect to do it on slopes obtained from models fitted separately on each period. Period needs to be a response variable in your model.

It looks to me like your last trend does not represent what is actually happening during this time period.

Comment: "it is incorrect to do it on slopes obtained from models fitted separately on each period" and how would you do that? I know for a fact those are the periods. What I don't know, is how to objectively measure a change in overall slope  between contiguous periods.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, wouldn’t it be an interaction between time*phase, such that change in Y across time depends on or is conditional on phase (e.g., color)?

Comment: I added some explanations.

Comment: It still seems as if you could model phase*time in predicting Y, and estimate the predicted effects for the separate slopes of A and B, right?

Comment: But if I understand you correctly, that doesn't capture the fact that at each period, a slope or trend already existed, it would simply measure the overall differences for A and B, if for example, a downward trend started in A but existed mostly in B,  according to your method (again, if I'm understanding correctly) B would have worse performance, when actually it could have been a good performance because a downward trend already started in A and maybe B cushioned it and slightly reversed it.